# ArrayDeque: addLast(E) + removeLast() would be same as push(E) / pop()? Does preferring addFirst(E) + removeFirst() have any advantages?

Tags: java, collections, stack, arraydeque

ArrayDeque [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#push-E-) state that `push(E)` is same as `addFirst(E)`, and `pop()` is same as `removeFirst()`.

I think the same effect could be achieved with `addLast(E)` + `removeLast()` pair of methods.

1. Is that right ?
2. Does preferring `addFirst(E)` + `removeFirst()` have any advantages?

Comment: `Collection` does not have `push` or `pop` (so if your code is written to the root interface, then you can't use `push` or `pop`).

Comment: Collection does not have addFirst(E), addLast(E), removeFirst(), removeLast() either.

Comment: True, but the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#addFirst-E-) interface does.

Answer (score 0):

The methods are summarised in the `Deque` interface. If you are using the `ArrayDeque` as a `Queue` use that interface, otherwise use the `Deque` methods. I's kind of unfortunate that `Deque` extends `Queue` as it is a `Queue` equally in four different obvious ways.